# How to access entrys created from the xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I've made a void method that adds pages to my tabbed page. In this, it creates entry boxes but they are unnamed. After the person has filled in the entry boxes I want to create a report from it. How do I access the entry boxes for the information?

This is the part that adds the new entry:

```
        grid.Children.Add(new Entry
        {
            AutomationId = "weerstand" + lusnummer.ToString(),
            Text = "[weerstand]",
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 18,
        }, 2, rownumber);


        //button and bottom
        Button Reportbutton = new Button
        {

            Text = "Report",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#093d80"),
            Padding = 24,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = 36,
            TextTransform = TextTransform.None,

        };
        Reportbutton.Clicked += GenerateReport_OnClicked;

        grid2.Children.Add(
        Reportbutton, 0, 0);


        //make page
        StackLayout stacklayout1 = new StackLayout()
        {

            Children =
            {
                grid,
                grid2
            }
        };
        ScrollView pagescroll = new ScrollView()
        {
            Content = stacklayout1
        };
        
        ContentPage page = new ContentPage()
        {
            Title = "LDTB-" + number.ToString(),
            Content = pagescroll
        };


        Children.Add(page);
    }

    private async void GenerateReport_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //yes or no
        bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Rapport", "Wilt u het rapport maken", "Yes", "No");

        //Generate report
        if (answer == true){

          //WHAT GOES HERE TO ACCESS THE Entry?

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could store the created Entry in a field. Or access it via `grid.Children.OfType<Entry>().FirstOrDefault()`. There may be a problem if you add more than one entry, though.

Comment: The point of the function was to create pages with 64 entry fields. Could I name it from a string variable? @Klaus

`
String name = " entry" + i.ToString():

Entry name = new Entry
        {
            AutomationId = "weerstand" + lusnummer.ToString(),
            Text = "[weerstand]",
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 18,
        }

grid.Children.Add(name , 2, rownumber);
`

Comment: Sure, this is possible. Which of the 64 do you want to access?

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse your `Grid` and access the value of entries in it.

You can refer the following code:

```
            var children = grid.Children;

            foreach(View child in children){
                if (child is Entry) {
                    string value = ((Entry)child).Text;

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("one value is = " +  value);
                
                }
            }
```